# why should we use n-way merge? what are its advantages over 2-way merge?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I tried to read few articles on n-way merge, but did not understand the concept. I am confused on why would you use n-way merge over 2-way merge? Like why would you divide array in 3 parts, sort them then do 2-way merge of 2 parts and then 2-way merge of 3rd part with this merged 2 parts :)

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a "normal" merge sort, you divide the array by 2, until reaching a depth of `log2n` and then start merging. Each merge of two arrays of size `m` would also take `2m` operations.

This gets you to the following formula (in timing analysis):

```
n/2 * 2 + n/4 * 4 + ... 1 * n = n * log2n
```

Now if you do a three-way merge, you will divide the array by 3. The difference with the previous method is twofold:

- The depth of division is now `log3n`.
- During merge, instead of comparing 2 elements, you need to find the minimum of 3 elements.

This means that, in the most basic implementation, you will get such a formula:

```
n/3 * 2*3 + n/9 * 2*9 + ... 1 * 2*n = 2 * n * log3n
```

Note that 2 is multiplied because finding the minimum of three elements consists of 2 operations.

Asymptotically, these two are both `Θ(nlogn)`. However, perhaps (I haven't tried) in practice the three-way merge sort would give better performance because of its `log3n`. Nevertheless, since `log2n` for n = 1000000 is a mere 20, and `log3n` for the same number is 12.5, I doubt this optimization would be really effective unless `n` is quite large.

---

With a clever implementation, a k-way merge may indeed have a nice impact on merge sort. The idea is that once you find the minimum of `k` elements, you already know the relationship between the rest of the `k-1` elements that are not minimum. So once consuming that minimum element from its respective list, you need only compare the new value of that list and find its ordering with respect to the remaining `k-1` elements. Using a heap, this would be quite trivial.

---

Be sure to also see [Jerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14713825/912144). I agree with him that the true power of multiway merge comes from dealing with multiple disks and parallel processing.

Comment: I'd say probably [what jerry says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14713825/912144) regarding parallel computation and parallel disk reads is the main reason for it though.

Comment: perfect, thank you Shahbaz, that is really a great explanation
now the part I did not understand is, after dividing into groups of 3 how will you do the merge? after I know min of 3, what will I do? suppose I put it at start of 3-element array, what about next 2 elements? Can you point me to a sample-n-simple code?
Sorry it may sound stupid, but that is the part I never caught hold of in 3-way merge.

Comment: The same thing you do with 2 array merges. You'd have one pointer for each array to the part that is not yet merged (in the beginning, it would be the beginning of the array). Once you find the minimum, you put it in the merged array and advance the pointer corresponding to that element. It's the same problem again, you have three pointers, find minimum, append it to the merged array and advance that pointer. Repeat.

Answer (score 15):

You'd typically end up with multiple streams to merge when you're doing an external sort. For example, let's assume you need to sort a terabyte of data, and have only (say) 64 gigabytes of RAM.

You'd typically do that by reading in 64 gigabytes, sorting it, then writing it out. Repeat for the full terabyte of data, producing one intermediate file for each "chunk" you can hold in memory at once. There are ways to improve this, but about the best you can typically hope for is that you produce sorted intermediate files of around 128 gigabytes each.

That leaves you with a number of intermediate files to merge together -- and the number will almost certainly be greater than 2.

If you're doing to do this on a regular basis, you probably have some pretty high-end hardware to do it with. If you've put each intermediate file on a separate disk drive, (and have at least one more for your output) you can almost certainly improve speed by merging all the data together at once, instead of only two at a time. The process will typically be I/O bound, so reading from (say) 8 disks at a time will typically be around 4 times as fast as reading from only 2 disks at a time (though this depends on your output disk having that much bandwidth, which may not be true). By avoiding creating more intermediate files (that will require further merging) your overall speed will probably improve by an even larger factor.